# Expected unqualified-id when doing ->[0]

Tags: c++

I'm testing overloading [] and + operator, but Expected unqualified-id occurs and I have no idea why.

BTW, I'm using google test on Xcode.

The error occurs on line 6 and 7

```
TEST (Speed, operatorPlus) {
Speed speed_0(3, 4);
Speed speed_1(5, 6);
Speed * speed_add = speed_0 + speed_1;

ASSERT_EQ(8, speed_add->[0]);
ASSERT_EQ(10, speed_add->[1]); }
```

And here's the Speed class:

```
class Speed {
public:
    Speed (double x, double y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    double getAbsSpeed () const {
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    double & operator [] (int index) {
        if (index == 0)
            return x;
        else if (index == 1)
            return y;
        else
            throw (std::string)"index error";
    }

    Speed * operator + (Speed & s) const {
        return new Speed(x + s[0], y + s[1]);
    }

    double & getX () {
        return x;
    }

    double & getY () {
        return y;
    }


private:
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
};
```

The code works fine if I use getX(),
but I'm not sure why can't I use ->[]

Comment: `operator+` should return a `Speed` not a `Speed *`  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: `->[` is a syntax error. The right-hand side of the `->` operator must be the name of a class member.

Comment: Don't use `new` or pointers, they are not needed in this program. Return by value. `operator+` should accept an argument by value or by const reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but with proper syntax. For example,

```
// x is an object and a is pointer to an object
x.operator[](y); // x[y]
a->operator[](b);  // (*a)[b]
x.operator+(y);  // x + y
a->operator+(b); // (*a) + b

speed_add->operator[](0); // (*speed_add)[0]
ASSERT_EQ(8, speed_add->operator[](0));
ASSERT_EQ(10, speed_add->operator[](1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would modify `operator+` return to `Speed` (not a pointer).

From @M.M's comment:

> argument to be taken by const reference (or value... basically
>   anything except non-const reference!)

```
double operator [] (int index) const { // modified
    // same body
}

Speed operator+(const Speed& s) const { // modified to const reference
    return Speed(x + s[0], y + s[1]);
}
```

then calling it would be:

```
Speed speed_0(3, 4);
Speed speed_1(5, 6);
Speed speed_add = speed_0 + speed_1;

assert(8 == speed_add[0]);
assert(10 == speed_add[1]);
```

Comment: Another improvement would be for the argument to be taken by const reference (or value... basically anything except non-const reference!)

Comment: @M.M, thank you for your suggestion. modified the answer.